# Asciidoctor - overflow on a large table

Tags: asciidoctor

I create a documentation with asciidoctor and Maven.
I need to put a large table (more than page width), but I don't know how to put an equivalent to css **overflow-x:auto** for this table.

my.adoc:

```
Tables :
|===
10+|*usertable* 
| id | hostname | ip | profile | username 5+|

10+|*tapplications* 
| id | category | feature | app_license_type | app_long_desc | app_name | app_nam_exec | app_short_desc | id_feature | logo 

10+|*licenseusertable* 
| id | date_since_granted | display | feature_version | handler | server_host | server_port | id_feature | id_user |

|===
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add some custom CSS to accomplish that.

You could supply your own stylesheet file, totally overriding the Asciidoctor styles, by adding `-a stylesheet="mystyles.css"` to your `asciidoctor` invocation.

Since you likely just want to add a style to the existing styles, you need to use a *docinfo* file. See: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file

Create a file called `docinfo.html` containing your styles. For example:

```html
<style>
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>
```

Note the `<style>` tag: the `docinfo.html` file is an HTML file (which gets embedded into the `<head>` of the generated page), so you can also embed custom Javascript, meta tags, etc.

Then, in the document containing the table, add the following attribute definition immediately after the document's title:

```
:docinfo: shared
```

Also, since HTML tables don't support horizontal scrolling, you need to wrap your table in an open block (which translates to some `<div>` wrappers):

```
[.scrollable]
--

Tables :
|===
10+|*usertable* 
| id | hostname | ip | profile | username 5+|

10+|*tapplications* 
| id | category | feature | app_license_type | app_long_desc | app_name | app_nam_exec | app_short_desc | id_feature | logo 

10+|*licenseusertable* 
| id | date_since_granted | display | feature_version | handler | server_host | server_port | id_feature | id_user |

|===

--
```